# Extract 2 Numbers from one string PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have string variable like below it have strings with two numbers

```
EUR 66,00 + EUR 3,90 Versandkosten
```

i need to extract two numbers  ex - both 66,00  and 3,98 separately to two variables. can anyone tell how to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i need to extract two numbers ex - both 66,00 and 3,98 separately to two variables. can anyone tell how to do this

There are lots, and lots (and lots) of ways to do this in PHP. Here are a couple.

```
1. sscanf($subject, 'EUR %[0-9,] + EUR %[0-9,]', $one, $two);

2. preg_match_all('/[\d,]+/', $subject, $matches); list($one, $two) = $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

If the string always looks like this a regular expression like so should work:

```
$string = "EUR 66,00 + EUR 3,90 Versandkosten";
preg_match("/([0-9,]+).+([0-9,]+)/", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Comment: You want the middle part to be non-greedy: `.+?`. Otherwise [it'll eat up too much](http://viper-7.com/jPJEaW) of the string.

Comment: Could you replace `.+` with `[^\d]+`, to match non-numeric characters? My regular expressions are a little rusty....

Comment: the output is
Array ( [0] => 66,00 + EUR 3,90 [1] => 66,00 [2] => 3,90 )

Answer (score 2):

considering this string

```
$string = 'EUR 66,00 + EUR 3,90 Versandkosten';
$ar=explode($string,' ');
$a=$ar[1];
$b=$ar[4];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('#([0-9,]+).*?([0-9,]+)#', $String, $Matches);
```

Your numbers will be in `$Matches[1]` and `$Matches[2]`

Comment: this also gets Array ( [0] => 66,00 + EUR 3,90 [1] => 66,00 [2] => 3,90 )

Comment: Yes, I know that. What's your point here?

Comment: only need 66,00 and 3,90 like numbers with ,

Comment: So... as I said - use `$Matches[1]` and `$Matches[2]` and don't bother about the rest of the array. This is how `preg_match` works.

Comment: Btw, if you want to extract "unspecified" amount of numbers, you can use `preg_match_all('#([0-9,]+)#', $String, $Matches)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the right one:

```
<pre>
<?php
// 1The given string
$string = 'EUR 66,00 + EUR 3,90 Versandkosten';
// 2Match with any lowercase letters
$pattern[0] = '/[a-z]/';
// 3Match with any uppercase letters
$pattern[1] = '/[A-Z]/';
// 4Match with any commas
$pattern[2] = '/(,)/';
// 5Match with any spaces
$pattern[3] = '/( )/';
// 6 Remove the matched strings
$stripped = preg_replace($pattern,'',$string);
// Split into array from the matched non digit character + in this case.
$array = preg_split('/[\D]/',$stripped);
print_r($array);
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: this retuns
Array ( [0] => 6600 [1] => 390 )
missing the , :)

Comment: you can remove $pattern[2] = '/(,)/';

Comment: Just a correction do not remove $pattern[2] = '/(,)/'; Just use number_format when you are going to use each number given by the array.